# jQuery never returns - callback function never fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I previously posted this issue on stackoverflow, but I had simplified it so it could be easier to understand and answer : this was a really bad move as I got totally inadequate answers.

I'm trying to program a Discord Javascript bot using NodeJS. The purpose of this bot is to fetch content from DeviantArt, using their OAuth2 client_id/client_secret authentification method.

My problem is that once the jQuery request is sent, it never goes back and the callback function is never called : so I cannot know what failed because the "status" var stays blank.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var doc = jsdom();
var window = doc.defaultView;
var $ = require('jquery')(window);

var jsonFinal = '';
var token_url = 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token';
$.get( token_url, { grant_type: 'client_credentials', client_id: 5946, client_secret: 'whatever'} ).done(function( data ) {
        jsonFinal = "("+data.status+data.error+")\n"+data;
        console.log(jsonFinal);
    });
```

(I'm using jsdom and jquery on nodeJS 6)

I followed the DA API documentation and I'm pretty sure that these are the right values to send to their server and that this is the right way to send them.

However, the console.log() in this code is never triggered.

How ? Why ?

Comment: Add a `fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {})` callback to check the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you shouldn't put a function as an argument in your done function. But just in case there is some other problem try this:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var doc = jsdom();
var window = doc.defaultView;
var $ = require('jquery')(window);

var jsonFinal = '';
var token_url = 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token';
$.get( token_url, {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: 5946, 
    client_secret: 'whatever'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    jsonFinal = "("+data.status+data.error+")\n"+data;
    console.log(jsonFinal);
})
.fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: Okay so this is a bit better. Here is what I've got now:
http://i.imgur.com/ZRKVbPY.jpg

Comment: yes! A result! You have an error in your connection. So your script is actually doing well, but there is probably something wrong on the server. Are your authentication settings correct?
What is the statuscode? (error.statusCode())
What are the responseheaders? (error.getResponseHeader())